# How can I know which friends accepted my FB app request?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I sent an invitation to try my app to all my friends! But I need to know which friends have accepted my apprequest in order to send them App Notifications, since If I don't know they accepted my app request It doesn't make any sense to send them App Notifications.

Is there a way in Javascript or using FB.api to check if a FB_id, etc. is using my app?

Maybe It's not possible to know it, I don't know, but any help is welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks CBroe !! Actually I googled it but It didn't show me that topic. Thanks It worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

in your app's admin panel on left side top there are a notification bar ! there you can get who accepted your app request ! for that you should use your fb account as your app id means if your app id is xyz then click top right * then use fb as xyz. then your admin panel will show you everything !

Comment: But man, If I have to send hundred or thousand of app request, I won't check them one by one... I need to do it programatically in order to re-send them an app request, or send them an app notification. Thanks anyway for your answer ;)